# Convert datetime to get month name in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

Datetime column data is as `2016-11-03 00:00:00`. I want to get month and year from this and convert month number as month name.

E.g.:

`2016-11-03 00:00:00` --> November 2016

### Code Snippet

```
..WHERE MONTHNAME(MONTH(S.date)) AND YEAR(S.date) = '$date'..
```

### Month year picker code

This outputs month/year format as "November 2016".

```
if(isset($_POST['monthPicker'])){$date = $_POST['monthPicker'];}
```

Database column name for datetime is "S.date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use concat

```
"select ..... 
 ...
where concat(MONTHNAME(S.date), ' ' , YEAR(S.date))  = '$date';"
```

Comment: @EKBG   does  the magic but  you assign the right answer at a anwer that seems  wrong ... ( or my is wrong.. ?) and you define  doesn't work ... weird .. if my answer  is right please mark it as accepted .otherwise tell me if you have some problems

Answer (score 2):

your Mysql-Query is false. Try this:

```
..WHERE MONTHNAME(MONTH(S.date)) = '$date->MONTHNAME' AND YEAR(S.date) = '$date->Year'..
```

Comment: It doesn't output the results.

Comment: did you adjust the Variables e.g. "data->MONTHNAME"? This was just an example, not fully functional. And if someone wants to avoid concat in where-clause, this is the better solution.