# Get month name from date time, count and grouping MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm trying to query data from a MYSQL database with the following script:

```php
<?php    
    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$password);
    mysqli_select_db($con,$dbname); 
    $query ="SELECT * FROM tb_bankdata WHERE YEAR(last_update) = YEAR(CURDATE())";
    //$query = "SELECT count(*), last_update FROM tb_bankdata WHERE tb_bankdata.anycolumn = 'anycondition' GROUP BY MONTH(last_update)"; --> Not Working
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $last_update = $row['last_update'];
                //$last_update = date('F,Y', strtotime($last_update));
                $progress = $row['progress'];
                $data .= "{last_update:'".$last_update."', progress:'".$progress."'},";
                echo $last_update . " , " . $progress  ."<br>";
            }
?>
```

and the output is like this :

```
    2022-01-03 11:42:24 , bank_data
    2022-01-03 11:42:30 , completed
    2022-01-03 11:42:36 , completed
    2022-01-03 11:42:41 , bank_data
    2022-01-03 11:52:25 , completed
    2022-01-03 14:23:41 , bank_data
    2022-01-03 16:29:24 , bank_data
    2022-01-04 14:46:16 , bank_data
    2022-01-05 09:34:44 , bank_data
    2022-02-05 16:37:16 , bank_data
    2022-02-05 16:37:22 , bank_data
    2022-02-14 09:24:57 , completed
    2022-02-06 11:35:10 , bank_data
    2022-03-31 14:26:49 , bank_data
    2022-03-31 14:26:58 , bank_data
    2022-03-31 14:27:07 , completed
    2022-03-31 14:27:16 , completed
    2022-03-31 21:35:48 , bank_data
```

i need output like this :

```
January, completed, 3
January, bank_data, 6
February, completed, 1
February, bank_data, 3
March, completed, 2
March, bank_data, 3
```

How to do QUERY, COUNT and GROUPING like that?
Thanks before,

Notes :
I've tried query in the suggested link [Convert datetime to get month name in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467598/convert-datetime-to-get-month-name-in-mysql)
It doesn't output the results

And I've also tried query Group by the month as well like this :

```php
$query = "SELECT count(*), last_update FROM tb_bankdata WHERE tb_bankdata.anycolumn = 'anycondition' GROUP BY MONTH(last_update)";
```

But it doesn't output the results as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert datetime to get month name in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467598/convert-datetime-to-get-month-name-in-mysql)

Comment: Group by the month as well. "Current result" wouldn't be the output from "not working". Provide more details about that.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I've tried this link [Convert datetime to get month name in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467598/convert-datetime-to-get-month-name-in-mysql) but it doesn't work (empty output)

Comment: I've tried Groups by month as well in the query but it doesn't produce any output. The query is like this:  $query = "SELECT count(*), last_update FROM tb_bankdata WHERE tb_bankdata.anycolumn = 'anycondition' GROUP BY MONTH(last_update)"; .... is there something wrong with this query?

Comment: That gives back 2 values, not 3.. Provide results of that query